# Prevent UITextField tag from getting overwritten

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a custom cell that uses a `UITextField`. I pass the data to the tableView for processing. In fact, You can have multiple rows so I keep track of it with `indexPath.row`

```
// I reuse this in all cells
struct Label {
 static func textField(cell: UITableViewCell, f: Selector, tag: Int: 1) -> UITextField {
   let t = UITextField()
   t.tag = tag
   t.addTarget(cell, action: f, for: .editingChanged)
   [...] // placeholder, fonts etc
   return t
 }
}
```

In a class:

```
// cellForRowAt
let foo = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foo") as! foo

foo.textTyped = { sender in
  let textFieldPosition = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.tableView)
  let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: textFieldPosition)

  let field = sender.tag // the int assigned inside foo's cell

  print("FIELD IS: ", field) // I should see the int for the field I'm typing in

  // I keep track of the row with indexPath.row
  // I need to attach it to sender
  sender.tag = indexPath!.row // But, this changes field

  // I use a switch statement based on field
  switch field {
  case 4:
   sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.fooTyped /* omitted here */), for: .editingChanged)
   [...]
  }
}
```

On first type, I see the correct int for field then it changes to the value of indexPath.row

The cell:

```
var textTyped: ((UITextField) -> Void)?

@objc func fieldTyped(sender: UITextField) -> Void {
  textTyped?(sender)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

 // More than one of these but with a unique variable to setup its constraints:
let foo1 = Label.textField(cell: self, f: #selector(fieldTyped), tag: 4) 

// foo2 = [...] with tag: 9 (for example)
}
```

A good example of this setup is the Contact app on your iOS device. Tap the "add address" and you see a cell. Tap again and you'll see another. I keep track of it with `indexPath.row`. One row has many `UITextField`s. The issue is, the assignment of `indexPath.row` to `sender.tag` throws off the `UITextField`s tag that I manually set, ie `tag = 4`. It prints "0"

I'm happy to post more code but this is the issue I have with just that bit of code. I expect "field" to print that tag as I type in any text field.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me and I'm open for improvement.

I need to move `indexPath` to the function Im calling `fooTyped`, then get the position:

```
// cellForRowAt
let foo = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foo") as! foo

foo.textTyped = { sender in
  // I use a switch statement based on field
  // sender.tag would determine Street1, Street2 etc
  switch sender.tag {
  case 4:
   sender.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.fooTyped /* omitted here */), for: .editingChanged)
   [...]
  }
}
```

TableView Class

```
// get row position
fileprivate func getRowPositionFromSender(sender: UITextField) -> Int {
    let textFieldPosition = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: textFieldPosition)
    return (indexPath?.row)!
}

// Then use it in fooTyped (street1)
@objc func fooTyped(sender: UITextField) {
    let position = getRowPositionFromSender(sender: sender)
    print(position) // This is what Im after
}

// Similar func for Street2
[...]
```